# graphics card issue?

Tags: windows, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, crash

I have a simple graphics card in a business system which everything runs fine for about a week but then I'll get problems where the screens will  flicker and I'll get multiple cursors and then the system will just crash.

is this hardware of software related? are there any stress/test tools i can use to check?

Comment: Are there any events in the event log? Are all drivers up to date? Are the drivers from the card manufacturer and not the chipset maker or possibly Windows Update. Perhaps some details on the OS and the graphics card might help as well.

Comment: Did you play "try to replace" game?! If it's aged card - it's card. Or it can be bad connection in slot. **Not** driver issue for 99.9%